# To renice the process paused with Control-Z

Tags: bash, process, nice

I want to renice the process that I just stopped using Control-Z without looking through the output of `top` or `ps`. I know you can resume a process, or a job in terms of Bash to be precise, like `bg 1` for example. But can you do something like that for `renice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the PID of stopped job by providing its jobspec to `jobs` builtin, and use it as an argument to `renice`. E.g:

```
$ sleep 10
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
$ renice -20 $(jobs -p %1)
26939 (process ID) old priority -11, new priority -20
$
```